Is there any way to get lcid of current session in a function with schemabinding option?
I need to get lcid of current session in a function. In a general case, I can get @@LANGID and then match it with sys.syslanguages table. But not in the function or view compiled with schemabinding option. Are there any other ways to get lcid without a direct call to the syslanguages table?

How would it make sense to schema-bind a view or function which returns different data depending on where you call it from? What exactly are you doing that requires schema-binding?

Smells like an XY Problem. Why do you need to get the value of @@LANGID in a (schemabound) function? What are you actually trying to achieve here?

I don't need @@LANGID, I need lcid

This is not my decision to make it schema-bind.

You haven't answered why you need the information from the system, @vbif ... If the answer is "because" then it's time to rethink your solution so that's it not just "because".

That's how the localisation of the project was made.

@ThomA Probably not their decision either, but I can imagine several scenarios where you'd want to match the lcid to something in the application (e.g. maybe they are using a translation table that is based off lcid and not SQL Server's proprietary langids).

Would SQLCLR be an option?

It probably isn't [their decision], @AaronBertrand , but I'm sure we've both had times where what we're asked to do, and what we know we need to do are two different things; knowing what the business needs, instead of blindly implementing what they ask, is what makes good developers. Why I'm trying to ascertain if this is an XY Problem.

i'm guessing that the program sets some language on startup, and then you wanna get the LCID when doing joins against translation tables, because someone was too lazy to pass the language from the GUI to the db. You could probably do a inline function with hardcoded values of languages you support and their LCID?

I think it what I have to do, because there is no better solution.

I don't know that syslanguages has changed in decades, so you could just make your own user table for lookups.
SELECT lcid, [langid] INTO dbo.LangMapping FROM sys.syslanguages;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX lm ON dbo.LangMapping(langid);

Now you can create a schema-bound function:
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLCIDs(@langid int)
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT lcid 
      FROM dbo.LangMapping 
     WHERE langid = COAELSCE(@langid, @@LANGID)
  );

(If you just want the current LCID, pass in null.)
If you're worried about the data changing over time, you could set up a job to periodically repopulate the table.
An alternative, as there are only 34 rows, you could easily hard-code them into their own function or view using a CASE expression (which you could also periodically rebuild if you're worried about lcid/langid mapping changing over time). You could build it using:
SELECT CONCAT_WS( char(13)+char(10), 
       '  WHEN ', [langid], ' THEN ', lcid)
  FROM sys.syslanguages;

Or if you want it to look really pretty, and include the language alias for self-documentation:
SELECT CONCAT(N' WHEN ', RIGHT(CONCAT(space(2), [langid]), 2), 
  N' /* ', alias, SPACE(19-LEN(alias)), N' */ THEN ', lcid, 
  char(13), char(10))
FROM sys.syslanguages;

Then plug that into:
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetLCID(@langid int)
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT lcid = CASE COALESCE(@langid, @@LANGID)
    ... 34 whens ...
  END);
END

e.g.
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetLCIDs(@langid int)
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN (SELECT lcid = CASE COALESCE(@langid, @@LANGID)
 WHEN  0 /* English             */ THEN 1033
 WHEN  1 /* German              */ THEN 1031
 WHEN  2 /* French              */ THEN 1036
 WHEN  3 /* Japanese            */ THEN 1041
 WHEN  4 /* Danish              */ THEN 1030
 WHEN  5 /* Spanish             */ THEN 3082
 WHEN  6 /* Italian             */ THEN 1040
 WHEN  7 /* Dutch               */ THEN 1043
 WHEN  8 /* Norwegian           */ THEN 2068
 WHEN  9 /* Portuguese          */ THEN 2070
 WHEN 10 /* Finnish             */ THEN 1035
 WHEN 11 /* Swedish             */ THEN 1053
 WHEN 12 /* Czech               */ THEN 1029
 WHEN 13 /* Hungarian           */ THEN 1038
 WHEN 14 /* Polish              */ THEN 1045
 WHEN 15 /* Romanian            */ THEN 1048
 WHEN 16 /* Croatian            */ THEN 1050
 WHEN 17 /* Slovak              */ THEN 1051
 WHEN 18 /* Slovenian           */ THEN 1060
 WHEN 19 /* Greek               */ THEN 1032
 WHEN 20 /* Bulgarian           */ THEN 1026
 WHEN 21 /* Russian             */ THEN 1049
 WHEN 22 /* Turkish             */ THEN 1055
 WHEN 23 /* British English     */ THEN 2057
 WHEN 24 /* Estonian            */ THEN 1061
 WHEN 25 /* Latvian             */ THEN 1062
 WHEN 26 /* Lithuanian          */ THEN 1063
 WHEN 27 /* Brazilian           */ THEN 1046
 WHEN 28 /* Traditional Chinese */ THEN 1028
 WHEN 29 /* Korean              */ THEN 1042
 WHEN 30 /* Simplified Chinese  */ THEN 2052
 WHEN 31 /* Arabic              */ THEN 1025
 WHEN 32 /* Thai                */ THEN 1054
 WHEN 33 /* Bokmål              */ THEN 1044
END);

Some sample usage here:

db<>fiddle


This is good, but I'd probably go with inline TVF function, if i read the question correctly

@siggemann Yes, just showing a simple example... since a user can only have one LCID at any one time. What would you pass into the function? It seems they were trying to avoid declaring/passing the @@LANGID. Otherwise they could just grab the lcid from a non-schemabound function, and pass that into whatever else needs to be schemabound.

i think he wants to do something like: select * from somedatatable t inner join somelabeltable sl on sl.id = t.someFieldId and sl.LCID = <LCID from @@LANG_ID> so in this case, it would be something like: select * from somedatatable t inner join somelabeltable sl on sl.id = t.someFieldId and sl.LCID = (select lcid from someFunc() x) or a cross apply. But this is a guesswork

@siggemannen The correct implementation relies on a lot of unknowns. The method is roughly the same, regardless of whether it's a scalar or TVF. I've changed it to TVF, hopefully your guess is better than mine.

Yeah, we'll see when he comes back with followup in a couple of days :)
